# Fixing a parameter to a distribution in JAGS

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc, jags, stan

In the Bayesian programing language JAGS, I am looking for a way to fix a parameter to a specific distribution, as opposed to a constant. The paragraph below presents this question more explicitly and references JAGS code. I would also be open to answers that use other probabilistic programming languages (e.g., stan).

The first code chunk below (model1) is a JAGS script designed to estimate a two-group Gaussian mixture model with unequal variances. I am looking for a way to fix one of the parameters (say $\mu_2$) to a particular distribution (e.g., dnorm(0,0.0001)). I know how to fix $\mu_2$ to a constant (e.g., see model2 in code chunk 2), though I cannot find a way to fix $\mu_2$ to my prior belief(e.g., see model3 in code chunk 3, which shows conceptually what I am trying to do).

Thanks in advance!

**Code chunk 1**

```
model1 = "
model {

for (i in 1:n1){
y1[i] ~ dnorm (mu1 , phi1) 
}

for (i in 1:n2){ 
y2[i] ~ dnorm (mu2 , phi2) 
}

# Priors
phi1 ~ dgamma(.001,.001) 
phi2 ~ dgamma(.001,.001) 
sigma2.1 <- 1/phi1
sigma2.2 <- 1/phi2
mu1 ~ dnorm (0,0.0001) 
mu2 ~ dnorm (0,0.0001)

# Create a variable for the mean difference

delta <- mu1 - mu2

}
"
```

**Code chunk 2**

```
model2 = "
model {

for (i in 1:n1){
y1[i] ~ dnorm (mu1 , phi1) 
}

for (i in 1:n2){ 
y2[i] ~ dnorm (mu2 , phi2) 
}

# Priors
phi1 ~ dgamma(.001,.001) 
phi2 ~ dgamma(.001,.001) 
sigma2.1 <- 1/phi1
sigma2.2 <- 1/phi2
mu1 ~ dnorm (0,0.0001) 
mu2 <- 1.27

# Create a variable for the mean difference

delta <- mu1 - mu2

}
"
```

**Code chunk 3**

```
model3 = "
model {

for (i in 1:n1){
y1[i] ~ dnorm (mu1 , phi1) 
}

for (i in 1:n2){ 
y2[i] ~ dnorm (mu2 , phi2) 
}

# Priors
phi1 ~ dgamma(.001,.001) 
phi2 ~ dgamma(.001,.001) 
sigma2.1 <- 1/phi1
sigma2.2 <- 1/phi2
mu1 ~ dnorm (0,0.0001) 
mu2 <- dnorm (0,0.0001) 

# Create a variable for the mean difference

delta <- mu1 - mu2

}
"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know JAGS, but here are two Stan versions.  One takes a single sample of `mu2` across all iterations; the second takes a different sample of `mu2` for each iteration.

Either way, I'm not qualified to judge whether this is actually a good idea.  (The second version, in particular, is something that the Stan team has deliberately tried to avoid, for the reasons described [here](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/generating-random-numbers-in-the-model/3608).)  But it's at least possible.

(In both examples, I changed some of the prior distributions to make the data easier to work with, but the basic idea is the same.)

## One sample of `mu2`

First, the Stan model.

```
data {
  int<lower=0> n1;
  vector[n1] y1;
  int<lower=0> n2;
  vector[n2] y2;
}

transformed data {
  // Set mu2 to a single randomly selected value (instead of giving it a prior
  // and estimating it).
  real mu2 = normal_rng(0, 0.0001);
}

parameters {
  real mu1;
  real<lower=0> phi1;
  real<lower=0> phi2;
}

transformed parameters {
  real sigma1 = 1 / phi1;
  real sigma2 = 1 / phi2;
}

model {
  mu1 ~ normal(0, 0.0001);
  phi1 ~ gamma(1, 1);
  phi2 ~ gamma(1, 1);
  y1 ~ normal(mu1, sigma1);
  y2 ~ normal(mu2, sigma2);
}

generated quantities {
  real delta = mu1 - mu2;
  // We can't return mu2 from the transformed data block.  So if we want to see
  // what it was, we have to copy its value into a generated quantity and return
  // that.
  real mu2_return = mu2;
}
```

Next, R code to generate fake data and fit the model.

```
# Generate fake data.
n1 = 1000
n2 = 1000
mu1 = rnorm(1, 0, 0.0001)
mu2 = rnorm(1, 0, 0.0001)
phi1 = rgamma(1, shape = 1, rate = 1)
phi2 = rgamma(1, shape = 1, rate = 1)
y1 = rnorm(n1, mu1, 1 / phi1)
y2 = rnorm(n2, mu2, 1 / phi2)
delta = mu1 - mu2

# Fit the Stan model.
library(rstan)
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())
rstan_options(auto_write = T)

stan.data = list(n1 = n1, y1 = y1, n2 = n2, y2 = y2)
stan.model = stan(file = "stan_model.stan",
                  data = stan.data,
                  cores = 3, iter = 1000)
```

We can extract the samples from the Stan model and see that we correctly recovered the parameters' true values - except, of course, in the case of `mu2`.

```
# Pull out the samples.
library(tidybayes)
library(tidyverse)
stan.model %>%
  spread_draws(mu1, phi1, mu2_return, phi2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::select(.draw, mu1, phi1, mu2 = mu2_return, phi2) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(.draw), names_to = "parameter") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(parameter = c("mu1", "phi1", "mu2", "phi2"),
                               true.value = c(mu1, phi1, mu2, phi2)),
             aes(xintercept = true.value), color = "red", size = 1.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ parameter, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous("Parameter value") +
  scale_y_continuous("Number of samples")
```

[image]

## New sample of `mu2` for each iteration

We can't generate a random number in the parameters, transformed parameters, or model block; again, this is a deliberate design choice.  But we can generate a whole bunch of numbers in the transformed data block and grab a new one for each iteration.  To do this, we need a way to figure out which iteration we're on in the parameters block.  I used Louis's solution from the end of [this discussion on the Stan forums](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/is-it-possible-to-access-the-iteration-step-number-inside-a-stan-program/1871/22).  First, save the following C++ code as `iter.hpp` in your working directory:

```
static int itct = 1;
inline void add_iter(std::ostream* pstream__) {
    itct += 1;
}
inline int get_iter(std::ostream* pstream__) {
    return itct;
}
```

Next, define the Stan model as follows.  The functions `add_iter()` and `get_iter()` are defined in `iter.hpp`; if you're working in RStudio, you'll get error symbols when you edit the Stan file because RStudio doesn't know that we're going to bring in those function definitions from elsewhere.

```
functions {
  void add_iter();
  int get_iter();
}

data {
  int<lower=0> n1;
  vector[n1] y1;
  int<lower=0> n2;
  vector[n2] y2;
  int<lower=0> n_iterations;
}

transformed data {
  vector[n_iterations + 1] all_mu2s;
  for(n in 1:(n_iterations + 1)) {
    all_mu2s[n] = normal_rng(0, 0.0001);
  }
}

parameters {
  real mu1;
  real<lower=0> phi1;
  real<lower=0> phi2;
}

transformed parameters {
  real sigma1 = 1 / phi1;
  real sigma2 = 1 / phi2;
  real mu2 = all_mu2s[get_iter()];
}

model {
  mu1 ~ normal(0, 0.0001);
  phi1 ~ gamma(1, 1);
  phi2 ~ gamma(1, 1);
  y1 ~ normal(mu1, sigma1);
  y2 ~ normal(mu2, sigma2);
}

generated quantities {
  real delta = mu1 - mu2;
  add_iter();
}
```

Note that the model actually generates 1 more random value for `mu2` than we need.  When I tried generating exactly `n_iterations` random values, I got an error informing me that Stan had tried to access `all_mu2s[1001]`.
I find this worrisome, because it means I don't fully understand what's going on internally - shouldn't there be only 1000 iterations, given the R code below?  But it just looks like an off-by-one error, and the fitted model looks reasonable, so I didn't pursue this further.

Also, note that this approach gets the iteration number, but not the chain.  I ran just one chain; if you run more than one chain, the *i*th value of `mu2` will be the same in each chain.  That same Stan forums discussion has a suggestion for distinguishing among chains, but I didn't explore it.

Finally, generate fake data and fit the model to it.  When we compile the model, we need to sneak in the function definitions from `iter.hpp`, as described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstan/vignettes/external.html).

```
# Generate fake data.
n1 = 1000
n2 = 1000
mu1 = rnorm(1, 0, 0.0001)
mu2 = rnorm(1, 0, 0.0001)
phi1 = rgamma(1, shape = 1, rate = 1)
phi2 = rgamma(1, shape = 1, rate = 1)
y1 = rnorm(n1, mu1, 1 / phi1)
y2 = rnorm(n2, mu2, 1 / phi2)
delta = mu1 - mu2
n.iterations = 1000

# Fit the Stan model.
library(rstan)
stan.data = list(n1 = n1, y1 = y1, n2 = n2, y2 = y2,
                 n_iterations = n.iterations)
stan.model = stan_model(file = "stan_model.stan",
                        allow_undefined = T,
                        includes = paste0('\n#include "',
                                          file.path(getwd(), 'iter.hpp'),
                                          '"\n'))
stan.model.fit = sampling(stan.model,
                          data = stan.data,
                          chains = 1,
                          iter = n.iterations,
                          pars = c("mu1", "phi1", "mu2", "phi2"))
```

Once again, we recovered the values of `mu1`, `phi1`, and `phi2` reasonably well.  This time, we used a whole range of values for `mu2`, which follow the specified distribution.

```
# Pull out the samples.
library(tidybayes)
library(tidyverse)
stan.model.fit %>%
  spread_draws(mu1, phi1, mu2, phi2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::select(.draw, mu1, phi1, mu2 = mu2, phi2) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(.draw), names_to = "parameter") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  stat_function(dat = data.frame(parameter = "mu2", value = 0),
                fun = function(.x) { dnorm(.x, 0, 0.0001) * 0.01 },
                color = "blue", size = 1.5) +
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(parameter = c("mu1", "phi1", "mu2", "phi2"),
                               true.value = c(mu1, phi1, mu2, phi2)),
             aes(xintercept = true.value), color = "red", size = 1.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ parameter, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous("Parameter value") +
  scale_y_continuous("Number of samples")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you hit on exactly what I am looking to do. I want to draw a new value of mu2 for each iteration without making it a regular parameter.

Comment: Also, after just looking at the stan manual, what I am trying to do is analogous to including a constant with known measurement error.

Comment: Got it; thanks.  It turns out there _is_ a way (albeit non-trivial) to get one sample per iteration; I've updated the post accordingly.

Comment: In JAGS, you could get one draw overall (not by iteration), by putting the stochastic node definition in the `data{}` block rather than the `model{}` block.  [Here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/71466030/) is a discussion about how you could do it in JAGS, though it is pretty unsatisfying from a computational point of view.